# Skip to first possibility in text with pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am using pyparsing and am trying to use the method Skipto to reach the first occurence of several possible Literals in the text.

Imagine something similar to this:

```
OneOrMore(SkipTo(...longer expression...) | SkipTo(...another long expression...))
```

And I cannot fuse the two SkipTo's as they are located in different classes and it would not fit into the current system to fuse those classes.

If I now have a text similar to this one:

```
...a lot of stuff...
Example2
...more stuff...
Example1
...stuff...
```

It only finds the `Example1` occurence and just ignores the other one. 
Now my question is how I can skip to the first possibility in the file and thus find all occurences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only trying to process bits and pieces from within a larger body of text, try using searchString or scanString instead of parseString.

```
from pyparsing import oneOf, lineno

sample = """
<<Lot of stuff>>
Example2
<<More stuff>>
Example1
<<Stuff>>"""

expr = oneOf("Example1 Example2")

for toks, start, end in expr.scanString(sample):
    print toks
    print "starts at line", lineno(start, sample)
    print "ends at line", lineno(end, sample)
    print
```

prints

```
['Example2']
starts at line 3
ends at line 3

['Example1']
starts at line 5
ends at line 5
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I will give it a try tomorrow when I'm back at work!

Comment: It is working now! I changed the "oneOf" to "MatchFirst" as I want to find the first of several expressions, but for the rest it solved my problem. Thanks!